# Const a unary function

Tags: haskell

The Prelude states that const is a unary function. The type signature is

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

A unary function takes one argument. Yet the const function seems to take two arguments and discard the second, which would make it a binary function. What is going on here? I suppose you can bracket the type as

```
a -> (b -> a)
```

but I am very unclear about the actual usage of const. Why is const described explicitly as unary?

Comment: Can you link to the description of it as unary?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant statement from the Prelude is actually

> `const x` is a unary function which evaluates to x for all inputs.

Note that it says `const x`, rather than `const`, is a unary function.